# bash command skip execution if file names doesn't match

Tags: bash

I use a bash script to execute a command in shell for several times:

```
for i in $(seq 0 202); do
    xqcdio.convert.to.general /global/homes/s/sufian/job-run/output/c2.avg.00$(($i*40+495)).data.save binarydata/c2.avg.00$(($i*40+495)).bin < input$(($i*40+495)).txt
done
```

The problem is if some files are missing, such as `c2.avg.008305.data.save` and several others then the command is immediately terminated.

Is there any way if I can skip executing the command if a file is not found and move to the next file?

Comment: The loop shouldn't terminate if one of the commands in the loop fails unless you are using `set -e` or similar. Are you? Or is even the individual commands failing what you are trying to avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `continue`:

```
[[ ! -f missing_file_path ]] && continue;
#put this immediately after do
```

to skip execution and move to the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Use `test` to see if the file exists first.

```
for i in ... ; do [ -f "somefile$i" ] && ... ; done
```